# Why is the gauge group of pseudo-fermion mapping referred to as $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and not $\mathrm U(2)$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, group-theory, spin-models, lattice-gauge-theory

The representation of spin $\frac{1}{2}$ operators $\hat{S}^{a}$ by pseudo-fermions (also called Abrikosov fermions) is defined by the mapping

$$
\hat{S}^{a} = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\big[ \hat{\psi}^{\dagger} \hat{\psi} \sigma^{a} \big], \quad a=x,y,z \tag1
$$

where $\sigma^{a}$ are Pauli matrices and $\hat{\psi}$ is a matrix consisting of fermion operators $\hat{f}_{\alpha}$ with spin $\alpha$

$$\hat{\psi} =  \begin{pmatrix}
\hat{f}_{\uparrow} & \hat{f}_{\downarrow} \\
\hat{f}^{\dagger}_{\downarrow} & -\hat{f}^{\dagger}_{\uparrow} 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The mapping Eq. (1) has a gauge symmetry under a left multiplication of $\hat{\psi}$ with an arbitrary unitary matrix. Hence I would call the gauge group of a spin Hamiltonian on which the mapping is performed $\mathrm U(2)$. However, in the literature the gauge group is generally referred to as $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.
Could someone explain the reason for this?

Comment: Which literature? Which page?

Comment: ? "Gauge group"? *Nothing* is gauged! The Jordan-Schwinger map operators $\hat S^a$ are *singlets* under operation by U(1), and their commutator clearly closes into an *su(2)* algebra. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Qmechanic: E.g. in the book "Quantum field theory of Many-Body Systems" by Xiao-Gang Wen in Chapter 9. More specifically the SU(2) gauge structure is introduced in section 9.2.1. "The hidden SU('2) gauge structure". An other example would be the book section 16.3.1 in the book "Introduction to frustrated magnetism" by Lacroix et al.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: I do not mean spin transformations that would be implemented by a right side multiplcation of $\psi$ with a SU(2) matrix. The mapping Eq. (1) introduces a gauge freedom in the sense that the terms stay invariant under a left side multiplication  of $\psi$ with an unitary matrix. I do not understand why this gauge symmetry group is generally referred to as SU(2) instead of U(2).

Comment: Ah, by "gauge" you mean "immaterial", not "local" contradistinguished to "global"...  Of course there is a loose  "dross" extra U(1), and it is ambidexterous,  in that you need not apply it to the right or the left. So what? It is deeply uninteresting, like all rephasings of real objects. You cannot dismiss it by inspection?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is obscured by the notation / formulation that Wen uses. Fundamentally, your spin transformation must look like something of the form

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_\uparrow \\
f_\downarrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto U \begin{pmatrix}
f_\uparrow \\
f_\downarrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{2em} (1)
$$

for an appropriately chosen unitary $U$. (It must be unitary to preserve fermion normalisation).

Left-multiplying $\Psi$ by $U$ implements exactly this for its left column, but not the right. Instead, it performs

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_\downarrow \\
-f_\uparrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto U \begin{pmatrix}
f_\downarrow \\
-f_\uparrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{2em} (2)
$$

whereas appropriate manipulations of (1) would instead suggest the transformation law

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_\downarrow \\
-f_\uparrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto RU^*R^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
f_\downarrow \\
-f_\uparrow^\dagger
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{2em} (3)
$$

where $R = \begin{pmatrix}&1\\-1&\end{pmatrix}$.

Now a generic $U(2)$ matrix can be written as

$$
U = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -e^{i\theta}b^* & e^{i\theta} b^*\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $a,b\in\mathbb{C},\ \theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$.

It is then a quick calculation to show that the condition $RU^*R^{-1} = U$ is exactly equivalent to $\theta=0$, i.e., the condition $\det U = 1$.

**TL;DR**

It is a special property of only $SU(2)$ matrices that rotations of the fermion pair can be represented as left multiplication of a matrix, using $U(2)$ matrices here does something that breaks fundamental commutation relations.

However, it is also true that in principle one could have used a $U(2)$ matrix for equation (1). This preserves canonical commutators perfectly well - as Lie algebras, $\mathfrak{u}(2) \simeq \mathfrak{u}(1)\times \mathfrak{su}(2)$, with the Abelian part factoring out (indeed this ultimately ends up being a trivial phase for, e.g., the $f_{\uparrow}$'s). Note that as groups though, $U(1)\times SU(2)$ [is a double cover of](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388818/obtaining-equivalence-between-u2-and-su2-times-s1) $U(2)$.